# Mousemove и Mouseout js

Tags: javascript

Есть таймер. Как сделать так, что бы, когда наводишь мышку на картинку таймер останавливался?
Нужно с помощью `mousemove`.

Comment: Так а в чём тогда вопрос? Останавливайте таймер при событии mousemove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var isPause = false,
timer = 0;

document.getElementById(ид_таймера).addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
   isPause = true;
});

document.getElementById(ид_таймера).addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
   isPause = false;
})  


setInterval(function() {
if(!isPause) 
{
timer++;
};
}, 1);
```

Есть переменные isPause и timer. Если isPause возвращает false, добавляем к таймеру 1 (у вас может быть использован другой метод). Onmousemove (когда наведен останавливаем таймер)- isPause => true, onmouseout (когда не наведен продолжаем таймер) - isPause => false

На досуге прочти => https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events

Comment: Похоже у вас опечатка - вместо ид_таймера вы скорее всего имеете в виду элемент изображения.